# Unable to create Nested while-loop

Tags: while-loop, nested, data-science

I am supposed to "Write a program that uses two nested while loops to print off the rows and columns of a 3x3 grid (numbered 1 to 3), excluding the cells along the diagonal (i.e., where the row and column have the same value)."

I tried printing row, col = 1, 1 by adding one to each iteration.

```py
row, col = 1, 1

while row != 3 and col != 3:
    row += 1
    col += 1
print (row, col)
```

Result should look like this: 
1 2
1 3
2 1
vertically 12 on top, 13 in middle and 21 in the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *nested* while loop generally means a second *inside* the first. I don't know what language you're using, but you should consider something more like:

```
while row <= 3:
  while col <= 3:
    print (row, col)
    col++
  col = 1
  row++
```

This doesn't do the diagonal checks, but it demonstrates the nested loop idea:

1. The outer loop begins with `row = 1` and `col = 1`.
2. The inner loop begins.
3. The inner loop counts columns 1-3, then exits;
4. The outer loop resets `col` to 1 and increments row
5. The next iteration of the outer loop begins with the new row.
6. Steps 2-5 repeat until until `row` = 4, at which point the outer loop exits and you're done.

Here's an example of this sort of thing in javascript, including the diagonal check:

```js
let row = 1;
let col = 1;

// do this block until row > 3
while (row <= 3) {

  // declare a new array to collect this row's output
  let output = []; 

  // do this block until col > 3
  while (col <= 3) {

    // add the column or '-' to the end of the array
    output.push( row === col ? '-' : col );

    // increment the column
    col++;
  }
  
  // row finished. emit the collected
  // row with a space between the numbers
  console.log(output.join(' '));

  // reset column to 1
  col = 1;

  // do the next row
  row++;
}
```

Comment: The result is quasi correct on here, but it's not running in Powershell for me. Also, I am supposed to skip the diagonals, i.e when row == col

Comment: I'm just trying to help you with the concept; not setting out to write it for you. Skipping the diagonals is just a matter of adding a `row === col` conditional in the inner loop. I've updated the js example to skip the diagonals and emit a marker for each row start.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Powershell so I wouldn't necessarily expect my pseudocode example at the top of the post to run, but the js example works.

Comment: Updated my js example to emit the 3x3 grid with skipped diagonals.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to be pushy @ray. Great thanks though! I was writing it in Python and I was able to translate it into a working python code. Thanks a great lot!